# Is this person on Slack being rude to his coworkers?

Tags: professionalism

At work a person by the name of David posted an image on his company slack random channel.   The image represents his opinion that most disease and death in our world comes from lack of diet, nutrition, exercise, sleep vs genetics, car accidents, viruses etc.

Later another person named Dmitry in the company posts a reply that seems to say David should go away because he is a drunj (I guess that means a drunk).

1. Is his reply normal or rude?
2. In his reply what does ", 2020" mean?

[image]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has nothing to do with anything.

Comment: Its not related to the workplace?

Comment: In response to each of your questions, in order: 1. Who cares? 2. Who cares?

Comment: Because I just like to understand everything about workplace communication and culture.

Comment: The conversation makes way more sense if you read Dmitry's first comment as having nothing to do with David's. It doesn't really make sense for him to refer to David as the year 2020 and if he posted that link within seconds of that comment it's because he'd already seen it. Dmitry said the year 2020 was drunk because of the NASA article, not because of what David said. This post is just a misunderstanding.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No.  He is joking, telling the year 2020 to go away because it is drunk.  It may be in response to David’s post about 2020, or, given the timing, might just be a preamble to his posting that weird science article that’s been making the rounds lately.

If you are going to look for offense in joke channels, you’ll find it, maybe stick to the work ones.